# Need to fill multiple text fields when a drop down menu option is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

For some reason this code doesn't work in IE9 (could not try other versions of IE). When tried it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox.. Text boxes comes up with message "undefined" when a drop down item is selected.

I am not able to figure out whats wrong, I wanted this working primarily in IE9... Any help is greatly appreciated..

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/RemPF/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't stop the function `printColorAndGroup` with a `}`.
2. You should use an **object** for key/value pairs, not an array.
3. You might want to use the literal notation for an object.
4. Inside the `onchange` function, you can pass the select with `this`. So `select.options[...]` would then be possible and cleaner.
5. Instead of names, you can also use IDs, so you don't have to worry about `[0]` each time.

Altered version: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/RemPF/1/

---

This is a literal object notation:

```
var colors = { apple:   "red",
               grape:   "purple",
               milk:    "white",
               cheese:  "yellow",
               chicken: "white",
               beef:    "red"    };
```

---

This is how IDs work:

```
<input type="text" id="food_group" ...>
```

And you can fetch the element with:

```
document.getElementById('food_group')
```

---

This is how passing the select works:

```
<select name="food" onchange="printColorAndGroup(this)">
```

with the following JavaScript:

```
function printColorAndGroup(select){
var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Yeah, I missed the curly brace sorry.. You are very helpful.. Thanks again..

Comment: Ohh, by the way that seems to be not working with IE, it worked well in Chorme.. NOt sure why, could help me with that??? I have tried in IE 9..

Comment: I worked out whats gone wrong.. Value was not set as we were getting  by value.. Thank you so much for your help... Below changed part of the code..                                <select name="food" onchange="printfryAndraam(this)">
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="grape">grape</option>
<option value="milk">milk</option>
<option value="cheese">cheese</option>
<option value="chicken">chicken</option>
<option value="beef">beef</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing } before your `</script>` tag

```
function printColorAndGroup(){
    var text = document.getElementsByName('food')[0].options[document.getElementsByName('food')[0].selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementsByName('food_group')[0].value = groups[text];
    document.getElementsByName('food_color')[0].value = colors[text]; 
}
```